# Подскажите систему распознавания текста для Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt, распознавание-символов

Возникла идея написать программу, в которой нужно распознавать текст с камеры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие существуют библиотеки распознавания текста (OCR)?
Я нашел пока что только [ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org/). Но не знаю насколько она подходит для моей задачи. Не будет ли это стрельбой из пушки по воробьям?
Есть также OpenCV, но как взаимодействовать с этой библиотекой из C#.NET я не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таки опять придется отвечать себе самому.

В Windows API есть пространство имен Windows.Media.Ocr для распознавания текста: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.ocr#